# ColdFusion doing OWASP esapi via Java

Tags: coldfusion, owasp, esapi, coldfusion-2016

I am have some old ColdFusion code. It was originally written for CF9, but is now running on CF 2016.

**application.cfc**

```
  local.esapi = createObject("java", "org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI");
  application.esapiEncoder = local.esapi.encoder()
```

Much later

**Regular page**

```
  form.Reason = application.esapiEncoder.encodeForHtml(form.Reason);
```

I am thinking of replacing this with

```
  form.Reason = encodeForHTML(form.Reason);
```

Do these function the same?

Comment: Yes, the `encodeForX()` functions use OWASP's ESAPI behind the scenes. `encodeForHTML()` is CF10+ and has a `canonicalize` argument, which takes the input down to its lowest factor. CF2016 added an `encodeFor` argument to a `cfoutput` tag for outputting. There's also the `canonicalize()` function that will throw an error that you can catch. That's useful for seeing if someone is trying to throw nefarious inputs at your form. There is no legit reason for double- or multi-encoding an input. The argument in the `encodeForX()` function doesn't throw an error and just returns the resulting output.

Comment: You should write that up as the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the `encodeForX()` functions use OWASP's ESAPI behind the scenes. `encodeForHTML()` is CF10+ and has a `canonicalize` argument, which takes the input down to its lowest factor. CF2016 added an `encodeFor` argument to a `cfoutput` tag for outputting that does similar. There's also the `canonicalize()` function that will throw an error that you can catch. That's useful for seeing if someone is trying to throw nefarious inputs at your form or site. I can't think of a legit reason for double- or multi-encoding an input, and I would interpret such as an attack. The argument in the `encodeForX()` function will take it down to its base evaluation, but it doesn't throw an error and just returns the resulting output. Personally, I'm not sure that there's much of an accidental way to pass a value that would be picked up by canonicalization, and I'd simply rather catch that attempt and kick that user off of my site.

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/encodeforhtml.html

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-c-d/Canonicalize.html

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:Encoding